# Example of ramified and unramified morphism of rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be Noetherian local rings. A local homomorphism $A \to B$
is said to be it unramified homomorphism of local rings if

- $\mathfrak m_AB = \mathfrak m_B$,
- $\kappa(\mathfrak m_B)$ is a finite separable extension of
  $\kappa(\mathfrak m_A)$
- $B$ is essentially of finite type over $A$.

I understand each bullet of the definition of a unramified morphism of rings.
But I cannot create an example for an ramified and a unramified morphism for the case that $A$ and $B$ are Polynomialrings over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ themselves cannot be polynomial rings, because they are assumed to be local. You can consider the ring extension $R:=\mathbb{C}[x^2]\subset\mathbb{C}[x]=:S$, where $x$ is an indeterminate. This ring extension is finite.

Then the principal ideal $(x^2)$ of $R$ is maximal and $(x^2)S$ is not prime but contained in the maximal ideal $(x)$. Therefore $A:=R_{(x^2)}\subset S_{(x)}=:B$ is a ramified extension.

The principal ideal $(x^2-1)$ is maximal in $R$ and $(x-1)$ is maxial in $S$. Now consider $A:=R_{(x^2-1)}$ and $B:=S_{(x-1)}$. Then $(x^2-1)B=(x-1)B$ because $x+1$ is a unit in $B$.

Note that the residue field extension (condition 2) is trivial in both cases, because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.